# Difference between np.linalg.norm(a-b) and np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a-b)))?

Tags: python, numpy, distance, knn

I'm trying to find the Euclidean distance between two images for a K-nearest neighbor algorithm. However, upon exploring some distance functions, I'm facing this discrepancy.

```
norm1 = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(image1-image2))))
norm2 = np.linalg.norm(image1-image2)
```

Both of these lines seem to be giving different results. Upon trying the same thing with simple 3D Numpy arrays, I seem to get the same results, but with my images, the answers are different. I'm not sure which one is the correct one to use so, any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: What's different?  Shape, values?  Big differences in values, or just the small floating point ones that we expect from equivalent, but different, calculation sequences.  You may need to describe your images.  How are they different from the simple 3d ones?

Comment: There's a big difference. For instance, if I try the linalg.norm on a specific image, it would give me 6834 and the other method gives 561. My images are (32,32,3) dimensional human faces.

Comment: And the array dtype?

Comment: They're UINT8 originally but changed to float64 after computations are applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the two gives **different results** in your case while the approach are mathematically equal. This is because `image1` and `image2` are likely of the type `uint8` and **`np.square` does not cast the result to a bigger type**. This means using `np.square` gives simply **wrong results** because of **overflows**. In fact, the subtraction already gives wrong results... You need to cast the input to a bigger type so to avoid overflows. Here is an example:

```py
norm1 = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(image1.astype(np.int32)-image2.astype(np.int32))))
norm2 = np.linalg.norm(image1.astype(np.int32)-image2.astype(np.int32))
```

With that, you should get almost the same result (possibly with a difference of few ULPs that should be negligible here).

Note that `np.linalg.norm` is likely significantly **faster** because it should not create **temporary arrays** as opposed to `np.sqrt`+`np.sum`+`np.square`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Checks out too, thanks a lot!